# Error with overriding variables. Invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python

```
print('Enter your monthly budget.')
myBudget = input()
print('Your monthly input is $' +myBudget)

myExp = 0
while myExp != 'Done':
    print("Enter your monthly expenses, one by one using the designated format. Once you are finished, type 'Done' to finish calculations.")
    myExp += int(input())
    if myExp == 'Done':
        break
    if myExp != 'Done':
        continue

print('Your budget for the month is: $'+myBudget)
print('Your expenses for the month is: $' +myExp)
Total = int(myBudget) - int(myExp)
if Total < 0:
    print('You are under budget by: $' + Total)
else:
    print('You are over budget by: $' +Total)
```

For one of my classes, we are supposed to create a loop that adds the user's monthly expenses then subtracts it from their budget and then tells the user how much they are over or under budget by. The main issue i am having is that the input for *myExp* is overridden by 'Done' to break the loop and i run into *invalid literal for int() with base 10:*. How do I change the code to where it will keep adding the inputs and prevent the variable from being overridden by 'Done'?

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink the logic here. You check if `myExp != 'Done'` multiple times, but that will always be true because it's always an integer. The actual input, on the other hand, is never checked.

Try organizing the code collecting user expenses in the following way: in an infinite loop,

1. get the return value of `input()`, store it in a variable
2. if it is equal to the string `'Done'`, break out of the loop
3. if not, convert to integer and add to the expenses